# Custom Communities Login Page With Forgotten Password Reset

Tags: community, custom, forgot-your-password

I have a custom login page for a community setup.  The site is configured to direct to the login page and does just fine.  The problem is when a user forgets their password and tries to reset it.  It sends an email to the user with the template assigned to the Forgot Password community setting.  The email template includes the {!Community_URL} merge field.  The email received contains a link to the custom login page with some type of reset token as a parameter (/Community/CustomLogin?c=).  When the custom login page loads it does not redirect to the change password page and thus there is no way for them to reset their password.

If I disable the custom login page it will link to the standard login page (/login) and then redirect to /Community/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword and allows you to enter a new username/password.

How do you get the custom login page to accept/redirect to the change password page form the forgotten password email?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the same problem and I just fixed it by enabling ChatterAnswer.

1. Enable ChatterAnswer : **Setup > Customize > Chatter Answer > Setting > tick Enable Chatter Answers**
2. Customize your site/community : **Setup > Customize > Chatter Answer > Site Setting, enable for your community**.

Just after that it should display all the pages you can override.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful.  This is either not documented at all or hidden very well.  Thanks, you saved me a great deal of time.

Comment: For me its not worked. Welcome email of Comm.. reg. is taking me to ChangePassword, instead of overrided page which i have mentioned in Comm. setting.