# Salesforce Community Forgot Password Email not sent

Tags: visualforce, community

I have my Salesforce community setup and created a custom Visualforce page to accept a username as input and then email a link to reset my password

Here is my custom Visualforce pages defined in the community:

[image]

Same with the site pages define my custom Visualforce pages:

[image]

Here is my Visualforce page to send the forgot/reset password email. I am using the standard ForgotPasswordController provided by Salesforce:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="ForgotPasswordController" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Forgot</title>
  <c:bp_header/>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="w-section mobile-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content bg-gradient" id="main-stack" data-scroll="0">
      <div class="w-nav navbar transparent" data-collapse="all" data-animation="over-left" data-duration="400" data-contain="1" data-easing="ease-out-quint" data-no-scroll="1">
        <div class="w-container">
          <div class="wrapper-mask" data-ix="menu-mask"></div>
          <div class="navbar-title">Forgot Password</div>
          <a class="w-inline-block navbar-button" href="bp_Login" data-load="1">
            <div class="navbar-button-icon icon ion-ios-close-empty"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="body padding">
        <div class="logo-login bigger"></div>
        <div class="bottom-section padding">
          <div class="w-form">
            <apex:form id="submit-form">
            <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
              <div>
                <label class="label-form" for="email-field">EMAIL</label>       
                <apex:inputText required="true" id="userName" value="{!userName}" styleClass="w-input input-form light"/>
                <div class="separator-button"></div>
              </div>
              <apex:commandButton id="submit" value="Remind Me" action="{!forgotPassword}" styleClass="w-button action-button"/>
              <div class="separator-button"></div><a class="link-upper" href="bp_Community_Login" data-load="1">Don't have an account? <strong class="b-link">Sign up</strong></a>
            </apex:form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content loading-mask" id="new-stack">
      <div class="loading-icon">
        <div class="navbar-button-icon icon ion-load-d"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <c:bp_footer/>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

I did create my own controller to send an email to myself and that work so email deliverability doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Not sure from these details. Have you turned on Chatter Answers? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48985/custom-communities-login-page-with-forgotten-password-reset?rq=1

Comment: Yes I have turned it on as per the question.